# Selected Dropdownlist value is always zero

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two dropdown list boxes, `Company` and `Vendor`, in my window.. I'm loading the second one, Vendor, based on the value of first one, Company,

```
ddlVendorContact.DataSource = Facade.GetAllCompanyContactsByCompanyId(CompanyId);
ddlVendorContact.DataTextField = "FirstName";
ddlVendorContact.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlVendorContact.DataBind();
```

Now I want to combine the box selected values. So I wrote the following code.

```
Value = ddlCompany.SelectedValue + ddlVendorContact.SelectedValue;
```

But my problem is, when I'm selecting `ddlCompany`, that corresponding value is coming. But for `ddlVendorContact`, always **`0`** is coming. I don't know the reason. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

I'm using two ajaxs to load both ddl values..
Now, after analysis more, I came to know that based on Vendor, Contact is loading thru Ajax..

What I got now is, once ddlVendor ajax is executed, ddlVendorContact ajax is not executing..

```
ddlVendor.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return Company_OnChange('" + ddlVendor.ClientID + "','" + ddlVendorContact.ClientID + "','" + hdnSelectedVendorContact.ClientID + "','MemberID')");
ddlVendorContact.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return Contact_OnChange('" + ddlVendorContact.ClientID + "','" + hdnSelectedVendorContact.ClientID + "')");
```

Thanks & Regards,

Sakthi

Comment: More code is needed to see the problem. Can you also show your markup for both DDLs?

Comment: @sakthi Can you post your code ?

Comment: where are you firing this: `Value = ddlCompany.SelectedValue + ddlVendorContact.SelectedValue;` ? just after databinding?

Comment: Please ensure that you are not reloading the ddlVendorContact datasource each time the page loads. You need to check for `Page.IsPostBack` before setting the DataSource for ddlVendorContact or else it will be overwritten on every postback.

Comment: did you tried dllCompany.SelectedItem ?

Comment: Which event you tried and what is the requirement. show more code

Comment: Are you sure you value field is "Id"? Are you for company set  company to trye?

Comment: I'm firing the "value" code on button click event..

Comment: When I checked ddlVendorContact.SelectedItem.Value by using breakpoint in that code, it shows the first item of that ddl, which is "Please Select" whose value is "0"..

Comment: @Sakthi are you checking `IsPostBack` property while populating ddlvendor?

Comment: @Sakthi Post your `page_load` code.

Comment: @Andrei, I can't get u.. Sorry..

Comment: @SurajSingh, I'm loading both the DDLs in "!IsPostPostBack" event..

Comment: @Sakthi So when you change your ddlCompany dropdownlist item , page postbacks and your `!IsPostBack` condition causes your code to bypass code for populating `ddlVendorContact` dropdownlist . Please check

Comment: Put your whole page here... So will elaborate more...

Comment: @SurajSingh, `ddlVendorContact` is populating correctly according to the value of `ddlCompany`.. Even after pressing the button, while I'm at code window for break-point, in browser the ddlVendorContact shows the changed value only.. But in code window, when I point my mouse over 'ddlVendorContact.SelectedItem' it shows "Please Select" option.. Not what I selected option..

Comment: @RonakBhatt, Sorry can't.. Because its my workplace coding..

Comment: If you dont put it then how can we understand where you are facing error??

Comment: @Sakthi Please check your `ddlVendorContact` is getting repopulated , see posting only code is not anyway harmful for anyone you can post it, your not posting any sensitive material.

Comment: @SurajSingh here is the Ajax coding, thru which the contact is loading based on vendor..

Comment: ddlVendor.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return Company_OnChange('" + ddlVendor.ClientID + "','" + ddlVendorContact.ClientID + "','" + hdnSelectedVendorContact.ClientID + "','MemberID')");
`ddlVendorContact.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return Contact_OnChange('" + ddlVendorContact.ClientID + "','" + hdnSelectedVendorContact.ClientID + "')");`

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet of code is a working example. Hope this helps.

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Sub BindList1()
    Dim a As New Dictionary(Of String, Int16)
    a.Add("sdsd", 1)
    a.Add("dfsd", 2)
    ddlList.DataSource = a
    ddlList.DataTextField = "key"
    ddlList.DataValueField = "value"
    ddlList.DataBind()
End Sub
Sub BindList2()
    If ddlList.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        Dim a As New Dictionary(Of String, Int16)
        a.Add("222", 1)
        a.Add("333", 2)
        ddlList2.DataSource = a

    Else
        Dim b As New Dictionary(Of String, Int16)
        b.Add("444", 1)
        b.Add("555", 2)
        ddlList2.DataSource = b

    End If
    ddlList2.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindList1()
        BindList2()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub ddlList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlList.SelectedIndexChanged

    BindList2()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim value = ddlList.SelectedValue + ddlList2.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I can add more Vendors and more VendorContacts to already existing Vendors.. For that, ur coding will not work..